# Hist function arguments - nclass, breaks arguments

Tags: r

What means nclass in hist function for example hist(b,nclass=10)?
What means breaks in hist function for example hist(b,breaks=10)?

Comment: Have you looked at `?hist`? What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

**According to ?hist:**

- **nclass**:
  numeric (integer). For S(-PLUS) compatibility only, nclass is **equivalent to breaks** for a scalar or character argument.
- **breaks**
  one of:

1. a vector giving the breakpoints between histogram cells,
2. a function to compute the vector of breakpoints,
3. a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram,
4. a character string naming an algorithm to compute the number of cells (see ‘Details’),
5. a function to compute the number of cells.

In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; as the breakpoints will be set to pretty values, the number is limited to 1e6 (with a warning if it was larger). If breaks is a function, the x vector is supplied to it as the only argument (and the number of breaks is only limited by the amount of available memory).

**Note:** What you might think is that if you apply `break = 12` you should get 12 breaks. But providing a single number in the function is used just as a **suggestion** as it gives pretty breakpoints https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pretty.html.

```
hist(sqrt(islands), breaks = 12, col = "lightblue", border = "pink")
```

[image]

**If you want to control the amount of equally bins (for exameple n=12) then you could do:**

```
hist(sqrt(islands), breaks = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 13), col = "lightblue", border = "pink")
```

where length.out is n+1:

[image]